# C# - an auxillary method inside a method?

Tags: c#

I have a method with quite a few local variables, and I would like the option to assign/modify a certain subset of these local variables. As an example, instead of having a block of code

`x=a;
 y=b;
 …`

etc. repeatedly at certain points in the method, I'd like to just have some function that would assign these values, so in the above I would just call
`f(a,b,...)`. The assignment might be a bit more complicated though - I might be using values from certain arrays, some variables might not be incremented by a fixed value, etc.

Is there some way to do this neatly? What are some good options? Maybe I should work with a struct that contains all those variables? Or I could just declare a function where I will pass a reference to all the variables, and also the values. Ideally, I would like to declare some sort of method that will implicitly know all the local variables of the method I'm currently in. However, my only goal is to make the code easier to read - the method won't be used anywhere else, so theoretically I'd be fine if the compiler just directly translates `f(a,b,...)` into the assignment code `x=a;y=b;…`

Does my problem maybe signify bad practice, and that I'm doing things wrong? Maybe I shouldn't be using these variables as local in the first place if I want do things like this with them - instead they could be member fields of a class. Then I could define a method that would do such assignments without problems.

EDIT - for more context on the problem:
my intention is to create a mesh-slicing method. Assuming the slicing plane is fixed, the arguments of this slice method are structs that are composed of arrays of various attributes of the mesh - each such struct contains the vertex attributes (positions, normals etc.), triangle indices, and the sizes of those respective arrays.
Into the Slice method I pass three such structs - one as the input, and the other two for the upper and lower part of the resulting slice.

Since all the vertices, normals etc of the input will be processed, there could be a lot of them, and I'm hoping for maximal efficiency (the purpose of this mesh slicer is real-time mesh slicing in Unity), I cache all of these as local variables (to avoid dereferencing the argument struct all the time). This might be a big mistake and a case of overly early optimization.
But I wanted to try it, since I would have probably tried it later anyway to see if it helps. Now as I'm processing the vertices of the input mesh, if I find that I should add the vertex into the upper/lower mesh, I check if I've already done so, and if not, I add it, and also set all the normals etc. Here is the code for "processing" a triangle of the input mesh that has been deemed as lying above the slicing plane, and is to be added to the upper mesh.

`currentlyProcessedIndices[j]` is the index of the jth point of the current triangle (index in the vertex array of the input mesh).

```
for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    //add vertex if not already present
    if (!vertAlreadyInUpper[currentlyProcessedIndices[j]])
    {                        
        verticesU[vertexCountU] = vertices[currentlyProcessedIndices[j]];
        //set the appropriate normals etc.
        normalsU[vertexCountU] = normals[currentlyProcessedIndices[j]];
        tangentsU[vertexCountU] = tangents[currentlyProcessedIndices[j]];
        uvU[vertexCountU] = uv[currentlyProcessedIndices[j]];
        colorsU[vertexCountU] = colors[currentlyProcessedIndices[j]];  
        //set the vertPosition and  change "has been processed to true"
        vertPositionInUpper[currentlyProcessedIndices[j]] = vertexCountU;
        vertAlreadyInUpper[currentlyProcessedIndices[j]] = true;
        //increment
        vertexCountU++;
    }
    trianglesU[triangleCountU] = vertPositionInUpper[currentlyProcessedIndices[j]];
    triangleCountU++;    
}
```

Now the code in the if block is repeatedly used throughout the Slice method with some slight modifications - it might be a bit different depending on whether the triangle that is being processed is sliced by the plane, lies below the plane, touches it with one vertex, or with two vertices. But it's all very similar. And it would seem like a good idea to use some sort of "local method".

Comment: First: Do the variables share a common purpose? For instance, the x and y coordinates of a point could be separate variables but they are better conceived of as members of a point structure. Second: how often do the variables change independently of each other?  We think of points as values in of themselves, and *a point* is a thing which varies. Tell us more about the purpose of these variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since C# 7.0, you can use [Local functions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions):

```
void MyMethod()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    AssignCoordinates(4, 5);

    void AssignCoordinates(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

As @Tarek says, since C# 8.0, you can make them static. See 
[C# 8: Static Local Functions and Using Declarations (Telerik)](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/c-8-static-local-functions-and-using-declarations). You can make then static, if they do not access local variables and parameters of the surrounding method.

---

But as Eric says, probably creating a point structure would be more appropriate. Either create your own or use an existing one like `System.Drawing.Point` or `PointF`. These structs have a bunch of useful methods and overload some operators.

```
Point p = new Point(4, 5);
Point p2 = p + new Size(10, 10); // Move p by (10, 10)
```

---

You could also use [C# tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples). The disadvantage is that you cannot give a tuple type a type name that can be reused somewhere else. This forces you to repeat the tuple declaration at many places. Therefore, they are mainly useful for intermediate results used locally and for pattern matching. See: [Do more with patterns in C# 8.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/).

---

**Edit** (after you have given more context):
It would make sense to regroup things belonging together in a wrapper type.

Be aware that you cannot easily modify a member of a struct inside a collection (e.g. a `List<T>`, since the indexer will return a **copy** of the struct, not a reference to the struct. Therefore, doing something like `mylist[i].X = 5;` does not work, since only the copy is affected, not the element inside the list. You must reassign the whole element `mylist[i] = new Point(5, mylist[i].Y);`. With arrays this works, since indexing an array results in a reference pointing into the array. Therefore, to avoid this pitfall, it is a good idea to make structs read-only and to initialize them with constructor parameters. Or you can use a class.

For example, you could declare a `Mesh` type containing a vertex, a normal, a tangent, a uv and a color.

using the temp

```
 int currentIndex = currentlyProcessedIndices[j]; // Recommended optimization!
```

you could replace

```
verticesU[vertexCountU] = vertices[currentIndex];
normalsU[vertexCountU] = normals[currentIndex];
tangentsU[vertexCountU] = tangents[currentIndex];
uvU[vertexCountU] = uv[currentIndex];
colorsU[vertexCountU] = colors[currentIndex];
```

by

```
meshU[vertexCountU] = mesh[currentIndex];
```

Comment: And in C# 8 those local functions can be static.

Comment: This is a good idea, but in your specific example I would be inclined to make the coordinates their own structure; it seems like "assign coordinates" is in fact the constructor of a point struct.

Comment: @EricLippert, yes. unfortunately, the OP shows only very little code.

Answer (score 3):

```
int x;
int y;

Action<int, int> f = (a, b) => 
{
  x = a;
  y = b;
};

f(1, 2); // assign 1 to x and 2 to y
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/nQ9iVH

Edit:

It's not inherently bad to use this pattern, if you are dealing with relatively transient data that stays within the method.

If you were passing a lot of data around between classes, or felt that a collection of data were better represented by a class, then classes would be preferable.

In this simple use case, an inline Action is fine.

And if you need a local function that returns a result, you can use

```
Func<X1, X2, .. Xn, T>
```

Where X1, X2, ... Xn are the inputs and T is the return type, and n >= 0.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I should work with a struct that contains all those variables?

Yes, it could be great way ([as Eric Lippert suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)):

```
public struct Coordinates
{
     public int X;
     public int Y;

     public Coordinates(int x, int y)
     {
         X = x;
         Y = y;
     }
}
```

and usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var coordinates = new Coordinates(1, 2);
}
```